# How to sort a specific column in multiple Google sheets

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to sort the forth column of more than one sheet in ascending order.
I can do this in the active sheet (sheet1), but can not figure out how to do it in the non-active sheets.

Below is my code.

---

```
function sort() {   

   var bus = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URI");    
   var sheet = bus.getSheets()[0];   

   sheet.sort(4,true);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting just the first sheet, get all of them in a variable (notice the absence of the zero index - [0]):

```
var sheets = bus.getSheets();
```

Then iterate through all of them in a `FOR` loop:

```
for( sheet in sheets)
  sheets[ sheet ].sort(4,true);
```

That will sort every sheet in the active Spreadsheet, you can also open sheets by ID, URL, name and the position in Spreadsheet, to find the methods you want just [read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet).